# Generate SOAP xml from wsdl file using Suds Python

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds

I'm a part of testing team who uses Python. Now we've got the requirement to automate the SOAP calls using Python. I have a WSDL file and we have some test data in CSV.

So for any particular method, I want to fetch data from the CSV and pass it to the service as parameter for the method and trigger the call, then output the response.

The help that I wanted is can we generate the SOAP xml from the given WSDL file for a particular method? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Yes, the SOAP client produces the XML for a particular call.

Answer (score 0):

If your CSV file has column headers corresponding to the arguments of the WSDL method you want to test, you can easily do that:

```
import csv
import suds

WSDL = 'http://some.wsdl.somewhere/'
METHOD = 'theMethodToTest'
CSVFN = '/some/csv/file.csv'

client = suds.client.Client(WSDL)

with open(CSVFN, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for kwargs in reader:
        getattr(client.service, METHOD)(**kwargs)
```

**UPDATE 1**

If you want to map a CSV *flat* file structure to a complex structure, then you could use the CSV headers to indicate a mapping.

You could map to a dict and pass it to the WSDL method as described in the SUDS documentation: [ComplexArgumentsUsingDict](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#ComplexArgumentsUsingPythondict).

Your CSV headers could be something like:

```
person.name.first,person.name.last,person.age,person.phone.0.npa,person.phone.0.nxx,person.phone.0.number
"Elmer","Fudd",35,202,555,1212
```

that would be converted to:

```
kwargs = {
    'person': {
        'name': {'first':'Elmer', 'last':'Fudd'},
        'age': 35,
        'phone': [
            {'npa':202, 'nxx':555, 'number':1212},
        ]
    }
}
```

I have no sample code to give you, though... :-)

One issue you may also encounter is type-related. You may have to explicitly convert data from the CSV file (text) to int, float, bool...

One idea would be to indicate the type in the headers:

```
person.name.first,person.name.last,person.age:int,person.phone.0.npa:int,person.phone.0.nxx:int,person.phone.0.number:int,married:bool
```

Or: store your test data in XML...

Comment: I'm getting the following error: suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'Fault occurred while processing.'

The value that I'm passing is for complex datatype with some nested elements.